# Why Sheets IMPORTXML doesn't honor the currency of the URL

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a report for work by using ImportXML but I noticed that the result shows only the USD value and not the EUR value is on the website, Is there a reason behind that?

Here is the formula in Google Sheets

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.suissegold.eu/en/category/buy-gold-coins/2021-gold-coins?&change-currency=EUR","//div[@class='info']")
```

I expect to get a result like:

```
2021 Australian Kangaroo 1 Ounce Gold Coin 1558.36 EUR
```

But I get it as

```
2021 Australian Kangaroo 1 Ounce Gold Coin  1850.24 USD
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't honor the URL for the EUR or any other currency and keep showing the USD.

I tried to inspect the EUR element to see the website JS function that is converting USD to EUR to know which exchange rate or from which website the exchange rate is but I failed.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to run it via proxy:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://de.4everproxy.com/direct/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc3Vpc3NlZ29sZC5ldS9lbi9jYXRlZ29yeS9idXktZ29sZC1jb2lucy8yMDIxLWdvbGQtY29pbnM-",
 "//div[@class='info']")
```

[image]

[image]